# Найти строку с помощью регулярки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Имеется огромный dll файл, где есть вот такая строка:

```console
<product name="Veeam Backup and Replication 11.0" marketname="P20210401" upgradable="9.5.4.2866" preview="false" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ProductReleases.xsd">
```

Мне нужно вытащить оттуда значение `marketname: "P20210401"`, где product name - Veeam Backup and Replication, но он может быть и пустой: `marketname=""`, в таком случае и пустоту нужно забрать.

Помогите составить регулярку.

Comment: Можно попробовать так: https://regex101.com/r/TS1UgF/1

Answer (score 0):

`/marketname=("[^"]+"|"")/`
В группе `|` (либо) ищет всё что в кавычках либо сами кавычки

| Группа | Позиция | Содержимое |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match1 | 50-72 | marketname="P20210401" |
| Group1 | 61-72 | "P20210401" |
| Match1 | 211-224 | marketname="" |
| Group1 | 222-224 | "" |

### Update

См. комментарии.

Можно сократить регулярное выражение:
`/marketname=("[^"]*")/`
Квантификатор `+` — один и более символов
квантификатор `*` — ноль и более символов

### Update 2

`(?<=name="Veeam Backup and Replication 11.0" marketname=")([^"]*)(?=")`
Здесь использую positive **lookahead** и **lookbehind**. Это значит, что мы возьмём значение только если до него есть `name="Veeam Backup and Replication 11.0"` , а после `"`.
Сам Veeam Backup можно передать как переменную в коде, если имена будут использоваться в цикле.

```python
pattern = r'(?<=name="' + name + r'" marketname=")([^"]*)(?=")'
```

| Группа | Позиция | Содержимое |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Match1 | 62-71 | P20210401 |
| Group1 | 62-71 | P20210401 |
| Match1 | 223-223 | null |
| Group1 | 223-223 | null |

Comment: По вашим правкам: не нужно оборачивать все подряд в `[tag:...]`. Это нужно только когда идет речь о метке stackoverflow, а не для обертывания каждого подходящего ключевого слова.

Comment: @insolor принял. Но здесь ничего в `[tag:...]` не оборачивал. Понимаю, что это теги, по которым можно найти вопросы и ответы, а не просто что-то рандомное.

Comment: Не здесь, в последних ваших правках. Очень редко, когда нужно оборачивать в tag. Зачем из вопроса с упоминанием python (условно) может понадобиться посмотреть все вопросы по python? Это не википедия, это сайт вопросов и ответов. Лишнее форматирование только отвлекает - в том числе выделение заголовками, жирным, выделение не-кода (каких-нибудь терминов, типа http) кодом.

Comment: Вот в этом вопросе зачем "dll" выделять как код? Это не код, это расширение файла.

Comment: @insolor понял. На длинных текстах, по моему скромному мнению, повышает читаемость. Но не буду злоупотреблять.

Comment: @DiMithras, вы можете  эту часть `"[^"]+"|""` написать так `"[^"]*"`. Квантификаторы `+` - один и более символов, `*` - ноль и более символов

Comment: @ipatev_nn очень хорошее замечание, спасибо!

Comment: Поправка: мне нужно вытащить этот marketname, где продукт name - Veeam Backup and Replication

Comment: @Vladimir надо учитывать содержание атрибута `name`?

Comment: @DiMithras да, мне нужно узнать market name у продукта Veeam Backup and Replication

Comment: @Vladimir обновил. Может так подойдёт?

Comment: @DiMithras Почти) У меня не обязательно 11-я версия у продукта, там после него может написано что угодно внутри кавычек, я попытался добавить, но у меня ошибка паттерна)

Comment: `(?<=name="Veeam Backup and Replication).*" marketname="([^"]*)(?=")` Можно вот так. Соответственно надо будет группу брать.